# How can I detect lockscreen status to choose between CallKit and LocalNotification for incoming calls?

Tags: ios, xamarin, webrtc, callkit, pushkit

How to detect phone lockscreen status in a PushKit delegate to choose between notifying the Call to CallKit or using a LocalNotification to notify the user. The aim is to avoid having users actually have to Tap the video button when answering from lockscreen (Because more often then not, test users can't figure it out and get frustrated).

We have a Chat application written in Xamarin that supports audio/video calls over WebRTC. 
On iOS incoming calls when the app is in the background or closed are handled using PushKit. 
We also implemented CallKit looking to get a more native feel. 
But when we receive a call on a locked screen iOS device, after answering CallKit UI stays on top, and we can only move to video call if the user taps the button. 
The fact is that CallKit UI answering behavior is inconsistent between Foreground, Background and Locked states, and our users usually can't figure out why they are not getting the App Call UI after answering on locked screen.

We noticed that WhatsApp has worked around the problem by reverting to a visible notification when the screen is locked, and only seems to use CallKit when unlocked, but we can't figure out how to replicate this behavior.

How can we reliably detect Phone lock screen status in our PushKit delegate?

We have tried monitoring screen brightness, but it always gives the same value regardless of state.

Comment: As far as I can tell, WhatsApp always use local notifications for incoming video calls, regardless of the lock state of the phone. They use CallKit only for audio calls.

Comment: Please check the thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70079